# Googlebot requesting pages of 1 site on another site

Tags: seo, googlebot

**Problem**: Using [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io) to index/store pages of one site, I keep getting path requests that only exist on my old site

*Example*: on Prerender I'll see that Googlebot requested `http://www.new-site.com/old/site/path`

I have an old website `old-website.com` and a new one (`new-site.com`).

Both websites are on separate servers with different IP addresses, (though `old-website` used to live on the server that `new-site` now lives on. `new-site` does not have these old path URL's anywhere in any of the site-maps, additionally these pages return 404's.

I'm not sure where to tell google to stop requesting these pages. For a quick solution I've added these to my robots.txt but that feels like a short term hack. The new site is a single page application, and old site is wordpress.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the DNS records and that the TTL expired?

Comment: Yes, they're using 2 completely separate sets of nameservers and have been so for over a year.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Are you trying to say you moved the web site over a year ago?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't believe I fully understand your question then. I moved the website over a year ago, correct. The nameserver that new-site.com uses has never been used previously whereas cloudns was used for the old site (when it was on the same server/IP address) and new-site was on cloudns for a short while before moving it. What would be the best way to hard-expire these TTL's?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that might help you here

Have you put a 301 redirect on the site? If not do it straight away as well as any relevant pages that need to be redirected.

Have you updated the site maps through search console?

Have you tried to manually switch over links?

Answer (score 0):

Ask this question in the [Google Webmaster Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/webmasters), which is monitored not only by senior users with direct access to Google but also Google employees.